# Ancient answer flagged as low quality

Tags: support, review, low-quality-posts

I'm not sure why, but a four year old answer to a question was flagged as low quality for review:

[image]

I'm unsure if this is a bug, or if it's been flagged by another user recently?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was probably flagged by another user, and for good reason - the answer feels like it barely tries to answer the question.  It also doesn't attempt to dive into detail in the same vein as the [linked question and answer](https://serverfault.com/q/68146/185768) from Server Fault does, either.

I'm believing that this was intentional, and it's a good thing this made it into the review queue - there are a lot of answers around that aren't really answers, or are low quality - and thus, they should be reviewed.

Comment: The impression I got from the other linked questions when asking here, was that the appropriate action was to downvote, rather than remove?

Comment: A downvote is often a prelude to removing the question; a question with a negative score can be voted for deletion.  The question itself is not bad; it is just answered elsewhere, and is now too old to be transferred anyway.  Probably, it is best closed.

Comment: @Manetheran:  The question is okay (if answered elsewhere).  The *answer* is what the problem is.  Downvoting the answer itself also aids in removing it, as users with sufficient privileges can vote to delete answers with a negative score.